# Реально ли и как реализовать такой функционал в iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть экран на котором есть 3 кнопки по нажатию на которые отображается новые соотвтветсвующие экраны. Аналог TabBar, но сверху. Видел это в андройд приложениях, норма ли реализовать это в иос и вообще реально ли это сдлеать? Может у иос другие подходы к реализации таких экранов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579992/positioning-uitabbar-at-the-top

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо за ссылочку. С этим способом есть пара проблем. 1 - при горизонтальном режиме таббар плывет. 2 - на этом экране мне нужна бек навигация. на такой же экран с таббаром (только нижний), а она почему-то не добавляется